# Make part of PDF start on odd or even page in Dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I convert html to pdf.
Is it possible to make a part of the PDF start only on an odd or even page, for example, using the page-break-after parameter?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our tour to get a better understanding about how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution that works for me.
This allows new pages to be output from odd.
If you need output new pages from even, change '$PAGE_NUM%2 != 0' to '$PAGE_NUM%2 == 0'

```
$html ='<body>';
$html .='here is my html';

$html.='<script type="text/php">
            if ( isset($pdf) ) {
                if($PAGE_NUM%2 != 0)  //add empty page if odd one
                {
                    $pdf->new_page();
                }
            }
        </script>';    
$html.='<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>'; //start new page

$html .='this is my html which will start at odd page';
$html .='</body>';



$options = new Options();
$options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
    
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->set_option("isPhpEnabled", true);

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream();
```